# WinForms scrollable control touch behavior

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, touch

I have a SplitContainer which contains Atalasoft's AnnotateViewer. Class hierarchy is as follows:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control
  Atalasoft.Imaging.WinControls.ScrollPort
    ...
      Atalasoft.Annotate.UI.AnnotateViewer
        My.AnnotateViewer
```

Now the problem: As long as the content of the SplitContainer is smaller than the actual viewport, hence no scrollbars visible, touch input is interpreted as left mouse down, mouse move and left mouse up which is exactly what I'd expect and love to see. I could still use two-finger-panning to scroll the view. BUT: If I zoom the viewer, so that my content gets larger than my viewport, scrollbars appear and touch input behaves differently: Horizontal panning stays the same, but vertical panning now causes scrolling, even with a single finger.

The question is: Is this behavior Atalasoft-specific, WinForms-specific or system-specific and can I do something to change it? I'd like a single finger to always convert to left click and move. Two finger's for scrolling is fine (and already works.)

I fear that it is system specific because you can find the exact same behavior in Word 2010. Still, it's a Microsoft product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I begin to hate the fact that you so often get sudden inspiration after finally typing down your problem to a forum or similar.

This problem was now solved by re-registering for gesture events. You are able to register for all pan gestures except for horizontal and/or vertical single finger pan.

```
// adapt the gesture registration for this window
GESTURECONFIG[] gestureConfig = new[]
{
    // register for zoom gesture
    new GESTURECONFIG { dwID = GID_ZOOM, dwWant = GC_ZOOM, dwBlock = 0 },
    // register for pan gestures but ignore single finger (only use two-finger-pan to scroll)
    new GESTURECONFIG { dwID = GID_PAN, dwWant = GC_PAN, dwBlock = GC_PAN_WITH_SINGLE_FINGER_HORIZONTALLY | GC_PAN_WITH_SINGLE_FINGER_VERTICALLY }
};
SetGestureConfig(this.Handle, 0, (uint)gestureConfig.Length, gestureConfig, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(GESTURECONFIG)));
```

Details here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd353241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

I think this is the cleanest solution you can get.

Answer (score 0):

The SetGestureConfig API accepts an GESTURECONFIG struct as its 4th parameter. How can you pass in a GESTURECONFIG[] array?